# CNTK Asymmetric padding warning

Tags: cntk

When creating a model in CNTK, with a convolutional layer, I get the following warning:

> WARNING: Detected asymmetric padding issue with even kernel size and lowerPad (9) < higherPad (10) (i=2), cuDNN will not be able to produce correct result. Switch to reference engine (VERY SLOW).

I have tried increasing the kernel size from 4x4 to 5x5 so the kernel size is not even without result.

I have also tried adjusting lowerPad, upperPad (the paramater named in the docs), and higherPad (the parameter listed in the message).

Setting autoPadding=false does not affect this message.

Is it just a warning that I should ignore? The VERY SLOW part concerns me, as my models are already quite slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out if anyone else is interested in the answer.

I stated in the question that I tried setting "autopadding=false". This is the incorrect format for the autopadding parameter; it must actually be a set of boolean values, with the value corresponding to the InputChannels dimension being false.

So the correct form of the parameter would be "autopadding=(true:true:false)", and everything works correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You have a layer that has lower pad 9 and upper pad 10 at depth direction. Are you doing 3D convolution?

Comment: I'm using multiple signals per location, so I have 3 dimensions. What I saw in the docs said you should use width* height* channels